# How use DI with init properties

Tags: c#, .net-5

In c# there is new way to create object with "private" setter. It is "[init](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/init)" keyword.
So it blow my mind because before we have ctor's with large amount of attributes.
But I faced with problem - default DI .net mechanism doesn't pass object's to this properties. Is there way to stay on new wave and still use DI?

```
//nice and fresh way code to become readable    
public IContactsProcessService _сontactProcessService { get; init; }

//old fashioned worked way
private readonly IContactsProcessService _сontactProcessService;

public WebApiController(IContactsProcessService сontactProcessService)
{
    _сontactProcessService = сontactProcessService;
}
```

Comment: Just a few corrections: 1: There's a difference between properties and fields. You can (and should) still use fields when it's appropriate. 2: You can also initialize init-only properties inside the constructor itself.

Comment: .NET 5 is already out of support. The long-term support versions are .NET Core 3.1 which goes out of support in November 2022 and .NET 6 which is supported until 2024

Comment: As for your question, the default DI uses constructor injection, not property injection. This hasn't changed. You wouldn't be able to set that property even if it was public. It's possible to use parameter injection in controller actions and minimal APIs

Comment: Finally, the new code you want to use is far dirtier than the old, for multiple reasons. Where you store the service instance is just an implementation detail, so a field is the best option. It's not part of the class's public API, the way a public property is. By making `_сontactProcessService` public you expose implementation details to other classes. Finally, the naming convention for properties is to start with an uppercase letter. The code you want to use would raise quite a few analyzer warnings

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to inject all *required* dependencies in the constructor, and use init properties for *optional* dependencies. That helps avoid issues where some necessary dependencies where not set, and the compiler remained silent since properties are not required to be set.

Comment: Thank you guys. As you explained it to me I will not do it and stay on ctor side. And one more time thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [Quickwire](https://github.com/flavien/quickwire). It extends the default DI container with some useful new behaviors, and one of them is dependency injection using init-only properties:

https://github.com/flavien/quickwire#automatic-init-only-property-injection

Comment: Thank for advice I'm appreciate your help. But I'm interesting in pure .net solution. As comrades in comment section says I want to do not a good things.